# WebPack + SystemJS - How to add a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, systemjs

I want to include a file called `/assets/js/clusterfeaturelayer.js` to my project, in which I use SystemJS and WebPack and which has the following structure.

- /app  <-- angular app code
- /node_modules  <-- npm packages
- /assets/js  <-- other third party libraries that are not in NPM

The file is defined in a AMD style and looks like this:

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dojo/_base/array',
  'dojo/_base/lang',  
  'esri/SpatialReference',
  'esri/geometry/Point',
  'esri/geometry/Polygon',
  'esri/geometry/Multipoint',
  'esri/geometry/Extent',
  'esri/graphic',

], function (declare, arrayUtils, lang, SpatialReference, Point, Polygon, Multipoint, Extent, Graphic) 
{

});
```

I would like to use that component from within my code by `import ClusterFeatureLayer = require("ClusterFeatureLayer");`

But no matter how I try to include this file in my systemjs and webpack configs, it just doesn't find it:

Here is my systemjs config:

```
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things.
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ClusterFeatureLayer':        'assets/js'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: './index.js',defaultExtension:'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'esri':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ClusterFeatureLayer':        { main: 'clusterfeaturelayer.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router'
  ];
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

and here is the webpack config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: [
            './app/boot.ts' // entry point for your application code
        ],
        vendor: [
            // put your third party libs here
            "core-js",
            "reflect-metadata", // order is important here
            "rxjs",
            "zone.js",
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/common',
            "@angular/compiler",
            "@angular/core",
            "@angular/forms",
            "@angular/http",
            "@angular/platform-browser",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
            "@angular/router",
            "@angular/upgrade",
            "ng2-slim-loading-bar",
            "ng2-toasty",              
            "ClusterFeatureLayer"
]
    },
    output: {
        filename: './dist/[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: './',
        libraryTarget: "amd"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: ''
            },
            // css
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ],
    externals: [
        function(context, request, callback) {
            if (/^dojo/.test(request) ||
                /^dojox/.test(request) ||
                /^dijit/.test(request) ||
                /^esri/.test(request)
            ) {
                return callback(null, "amd " + request);
            }
            callback();
        }
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Comment: How can this be so difficult? I need something very similar in my project :(

Answer (score 6):

Do you have an export in your `clusterlayerfeature` file?

```
// My Module
var myModule = {
    myFunction: function() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
module.exports = myModule;
```

If you aren't exporting your module, any reference to it will be undefined.

Comment: As opticon wrote - can you maybe check clusterfeaturelayer.js (and eventually post the file contents here (or at least variable opening and module.exports lines? At the same time, it is good practice to use case sensitive names and references, so I would also check those and have them consistent in all places used...

Comment: Hmm no the module has no export - here is a link to the full code: https://github.com/odoe/esri-clusterfeaturelayer/blob/master/ClusterFeatureLayer.js
Does an AMD module need such an export statement?